# Fibonacci sequence stops kernel despite try/except

Tags: python-3.x, fibonacci, try-except

I'm supposed to use a try/except block when finding the value of fibonacci(n):

```py
def fibonacci(n):
    try:
        if n==0:
            return 0
        elif n==1 or n==2:
            return 1
    except ValueError:
        print("Input must be non-negative")
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

n=int(input("Enter the value of n: "))
print(fibonacci(n))
```

Here everything is working fine except the `except` block itself. Whenever I'm running the code, everything else is showing output correctly, but on the except case, I mean, if I enter a negative value the kernel just stops working, it shows the kernel is dead. I'm a bit confused about what's wrong here.

Comment: Try debugging, add a break point to the first line in the `except` clause, run one line at a time and the mistake will be clear to you. Enjoy your homework.

Comment: nothing in your function will throw an exception, because is it just addition and comparison and negative numbers work perfectly fine with those, you need to check if the input value is negative and throw the exception in that case with the `raise` statement

Comment: I just tried raise statement. It worked perfectly ok when I wrote the code using if/else statement. But when um adding the same thing with try except this is not just ok. except:
            if n < 0:
                raise ValueError('The value must be non-negative')                                               Did I make any mistake again?

Comment: Can you clarify in how far your task requires the use of ``try`` ``except``? There really isn't much point to a ``try`` ``except`` for fibonacci other than input validation – which should be part of the input-receiving-code, not the fibonacci-computing-code.

Comment: Yes I know , but  I gotta refine my function to handle  unexpected inputs with the use of “try” and “except”, where exactly I'm pretty much stuck @MisterMiyagi

Comment: So basically I figured out the problematic part, but still have a few confusion in the fixation. I guess I need to put some more time into try/except usage and give the code a try afterwards. Thanks btw :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your return is out of `try/except` that is why your `kernel stops working`, it returns no matter what input you will put through it. As you said in the comment you need to handle unexpected input. First, you need to verify your input before you let the Fibonacci function work with it. Hope that will be helpful.

```
from typing import Any

def fibonacci(n: Any) -> Any:
    try:
        n = int(n)
        if n >= 0:
            if n==0:
                return 0
            elif n==1 or n==2:
                return 1
            else:
                return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
        else:
            return "Input must be non-negative"
    except ValueError:
        return "Wrong type of input."

        
    

n = input("Enter the value of n: ")
print(fibonacci(n))
```

Hope this is what you are looking for. Should of used `Union` for return type hint.
Sorry, my bad, had to add `n = int(n)` to a function. Tried to be more clever than I am and posted code before using it ;)

Comment: That was quite a help! Thanks loads! [happy][happy]